# HTTPS with SSL Certificate in DART HTTP Server

Tags: dart

Does the Dart HTTP Server support HTTPS?  If so, how do you specify the certificate?  If not, are there any alternatives such as community created packages?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. Dart supports https.

See the documentation [here](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.2/dart-io/HttpServer/bindSecure.html) and a test [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/main/tests/standalone/io/https_server_test.dart).

Relevant lines:

```
HttpServer.bindSecure(HOST_NAME,
                      0,
                      backlog: 5,
                      certificateName: 'localhost_cert').then((server) {
```

Comment: First link should be: https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/be/dartdoc-viewer/dart:io.HttpServer#id_bindSecure

Comment: The current valid link for the test is https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/tests/standalone/io/https_server_test.dart