# How to implement a secure authenticated https session with Dart?

Tags: security, authentication, https, dart

I'm looking for some documentation on this, but I cannot find any. How can I estabilish a secure client-server connection with Dart, using it both on the server and in the web page? It should be possible to use the same user authentication and session data encryption code for both, simplifying things a bit. Is it possible?

Comment: Is HTTPS not what you are looking for?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20870300

Comment: I'm talking about compatible encryption libraries between client and server side (for example: Javascript <-> C# or Java)
Sometimes HTTPS is not enough. Specially when we are talking about protecting user data from troyans with access at winsock32 level where they can sniff https in plain text or BHOs objects that already have access to the decrypted posted data in the browser memory. In the past I have used a js -> asp.net, in witch the javascript encrypts and send the data received and decrypted by the server in c#. 
But now I'm migrating to Dart and I'm searching a way to do it all in dart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this package ist the most advance encryption library for Dart currently http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cipher